# Microsoft Graph API - Contracts - How to pull subscribed skus?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API I can see the contracts of my organization when I execute:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/contracts

A Sample Response below:

```
"value": [
{
"id": "107adc54-f77c-4b8b-9cc0-1759e8d0cdfer",
"deletedDateTime": null,
"contractType": "2",
"customerId": "75ace3eb-6bf4-4655-95fd-f3d0610924789",
"defaultDomainName": "test.onmicrosoft.com",
"displayName": "Test Me"
}
```

How can i query the subscribedskus of the above contract via Graph API.
is this even possible?

I tried

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/test.onmicrosoft.com/subscribedSkus

But it returns the skus my organization is subscribed to and not the ones subscribed by `test.onmicrosoft.com`.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer this based on the R&D that i have been doing for past several days.
I dont think that Microsoft Graph API currently supports any additional operations on the **Contracts** object as the contracts documentation link https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contract lists only 2 methods **Get contract** and **List contracts**

As of now the only option to fetch the subscribed skus of each of the contract is by accessing the azure ad instance of each tenant using the respective tenantid (obtaining the access token using the endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/token and firing the REST call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your organization acts as a Microsoft Partner.
This means that you have 2 choices:

1. Rely on the Partner Center APIs. Here is the PC API counterpart to the  Graph SubscribedSKUs API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-list-of-available-licenses
2. Impersonate the end-customer via the Delegated Admin Permissions, as mentioned in the active_coder answer above.